# Moving values from one function to another - Python

Tags: function, parameters

I am learning about python and I want to transfer some value from one function to another.

If you look below. I want to transfer the user input from the first function and then automatically transfer that to the next function to reverse the text. I am looking for some guidance here. I am new to programming so please forgive me if I have done something silly.

#Below function takes the users input and stores it

def stringreverse():
stext = input("What is the value you want to reverse?")

return stext

stext = stringreverse()

#This function reverses the string input from the previous function
def reverse(stext):
return stext[::-1]

stext = reverse()

[This is the code online - Repli](https://replit.com/@apatel84/FirstNameSurname#main.py)

Answer (score 0):

```
def stringreverse(stext):
  return stext[::-1]

stringreverse(input("What is the value you want to reverse?"))
```